# how to Add multiple selected uitableviewcells to an empty uitableview cell in a same uitableviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, nsarray

Hi I've 2 `UITableviews` (tableview1 and tableview2) in a `UIViewController`. I already loaded some arrays to tableview1 by using MVC method but kept tableview2 as empty. Anyway I need to load selected rows from tableview1 to tableview2 by tapping the add button according to the below UI or drag tableview1 selected cells to tableview2 by using `UILongpressgesture`.

[image: screen shot]

Can Anyone give me the links to a related iOS (`objective-c`) tutorial, instructions or a sample project repository to get some ideas.

This is how I loaded Data to the TableView1

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableView1.dataSource =self;
    tableView2.delegate=self;
    tableView2.dataSource=self;
    tableView2.delegate=self;
    self.cellSelected=[NSMutableArray array];




    //Personal Assigned Array
    SAassigned *psaUser1=[SAassigned new];
    psaUser1.psaName=@"Peter Parker";
    psaUser1.psaimage=@"men1.jpg";

    SAassigned *psaUser2=[SAassigned new];
    psaUser2.psaName=@"Michel Jordan";
    psaUser2.psaimage=@"men2.jpg";

    SAassigned *psaUser3=[SAassigned new];
    psaUser3.psaName=@"Tiego Costa";
    psaUser3.psaimage=@"men3.jpg";

    SAassigned *psaUser4=[SAassigned new];
    psaUser4.psaName=@"Ketty perry";
    psaUser4.psaimage=@"women1.jpg";

    SAassigned *psaUser5=[SAassigned new];
    psaUser5.psaName=@"Jimmy More";
    psaUser5.psaimage=@"men1.jpg";

    SAassigned *psaUser6=[SAassigned new];
    psaUser6.psaName=@"James Franklin";
    psaUser6.psaimage=@"men2.jpg";

    SAassigned *psaUser7=[SAassigned new];
    psaUser7.psaName=@"Peter Parker";
    psaUser7.psaimage=@"men3.jpg";

    SAassigned *psaUser8=[SAassigned new];
    psaUser8.psaName=@"Jessica Helan";
    psaUser8.psaimage=@"women1.jpg";

    assignedUsers=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:psaUser1,psaUser2,psaUser3,psaUser4,psaUser5,psaUser6,psaUser7,psaUser8, nil];

    }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {



        //tableView 1
        PACell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"pCell"];

        if([self.cellSelected containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        if (cell==nil) {

            cell=[[PACell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"pCell"];
        }

        //tableview 2
        PSCell *cell2=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"pCell2"];
        if([self.cellSelected containsObject:indexPath])
        {
            cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        }
        else
        {
            cell2.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        }

        if (cell2==nil) {

            cell2=[[PSCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"pCell2"];
        }

        SAassigned *assigned=nil;

        if(tableView == self.tableView1)
        {
            assigned=[assignedUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.persName.text=assigned.psaName;
            cell.persImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:assigned.psaimage];
        }
        else if(tableView == self.tableView2)
        {
            // not yet implemented / loaded - empty
            return cell2;
        }
        return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the selected row data into a separate array each time user clicks/selects the cell. and while showing the selected data into another cell, load them using that array.

Comment: Post some code for more help. Like what array are you using to load data in  table view 1 and `cellForRowAt....` and `didSelectRow..` code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create instance array object.

```
NSMutableArray *selectedArray = [NSMutableArray alloc]init];
```

then you need add and remove object from "selectedArray".

```
  if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [selectedArray removeAtIndex:indexPath.row]
   } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        [selectedArray insertObject:yourObject atIndex:indexPath];.row]
    }
```